# Realurl create paths with several parts like detail/land-1/name-1

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have an extension for items, each has several fields. One field is name and one field is country.

In realurl_conf.php i can create a url like:

**detail/name-1**

with:

```
name' => array(

                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_myext_myplugin[model]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_model',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => 'name',
                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                            'strtolower' => 1,
                            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
```

But what if i also want to have the country in the url, like:

**detail/country-xy/name-1**

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Realurl can only map arguments which are available. Therefore you must also provide the country to the typolink generation.